# Create obj out of Div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="myDiv1">
    <ul>
      <li>Abc</li>
      <li>Def</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="myDiv2">
    <ul>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I now want to extract some information and put them into an object like that:

```
var ob = {
        'myDiv1' : [ "Abc", "Def"],
        'myDiv2' : [ "Ghi", "Jkl"]
    };
```

My approach was very inconvenient:

```
var obj = "{";

$('#main div').each(function() {
  obj += "\"" + $(this).attr('id') + "\" : [";
  $(this).find('li').each(function() {
    obj += "\"" + $(this).text() + "\", ";
  });
  obj = obj.substring(0, obj.length - 2);
  obj += "], ";
});
obj = obj.substring(0, obj.length - 2);
obj += "}";

obj = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(obj)
```

As a result I got an array, but not the structure I need.

Is there a better way to create the structure?

Later, I want to pass `obj` as a parameter in an Ajax call.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvm2a8cn/1/).

Comment: `JSON.stringify`.....

Comment: @Rayon: Thank you, but is there a more convenient way of building the structure together, rather than "adding every letter together", like I do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gvm2a8cn/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your code much simpler by just creating an object directly. You can loop over the `div` elements within `#main` then use `map()` to create an array of the `li` text values the child `div` contains. Try this:

```
var obj = {};
$('#main div').each(function() {
    obj[this.id] = $(this).find('li').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // = "{"myDiv1":["Abc","Def"],"myDiv2":["Ghi","Jkl"]}"
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/y79uuauv/)

> Later, I want to pass obj as a parameter in an Ajax call.

Also note that you do not need to pass the object in JSON format to do this - you can provide an object directly to the `data` parameter of the AJAX request and jQuery will automatically encode and stringify it for you.